# Javascript retrieving error name and message from Error() object

Tags: javascript

I throw an Error using the `Error()` object in a simplified function like so:

```
function errorExample() {
  try {
    throw new Error('ConnectionError', 'cannot connect to the internet')
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error
  }
}
```

I want to be able to access the error name and message from within the catch statement.

According to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/prototype) I can access them through `error.proptotype.name` and `error.proptotype.message` however with the code above I receive undefined.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: See [custom error types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Custom_Error_Types) @ MDN if you want your own name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misreading the documentation.

Fields on `Error.prototype` exist on all `Error` instances.  Since `error` is an instance of the `Error` constructor, you can write `error.message`.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the name of an error is 'Error', you can override it:

```
function errorExample() {
  try {
    var e = new Error('cannot connect to the internet');
    e.name = 'ConnectionError';
    throw e;
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error.name);
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

See: [Error.prototype.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/name)

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
function errorExample() {
  try {
    throw new Error('ConnectionError', 'cannot connect to the internet');
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    console.log(error.name);
  }
}
errorExample() ;
```